# force an application to run inside eclipse similar to MS Office

Tags: eclipse

Anyone know how to force an application to run internally to Eclipse IDE similar to MS Word or Excel when opened from the product explorer?

Comment: I want to run AbstractSpoon's ToDoList internally to Eclipse.

Comment: You talking about Windows, right? The application must support [OLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Eclipse can show [OLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding) objects:

- [Javadoc of `org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE`](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/ole/win32/OLE.html)
- [SWT Snippets - OLE and ActiveX](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#ole)

So the answer to your question is: the application must support OLE (as MS Word and Excel do) to run it internally.